# Hair Covering Before Marriage?

Tags: women, tznius-modesty, chasidut-hasidism, hair, satmar

Are there any communities in America or Israel where women cover their hair before marriage? Do Satmar women cover their hair before marriage?

Comment: Steven Stein, Welcome to mi.yodeya, and thanks very much for the interesting question! We'd love to have you as a full-fledged member, which you can accomplish by clicking on register/login, above.

Comment: What I'd heard suggested is that the custom never caught on, as from when a young lady turned Bat Mitzva until when she got married traditionally wasn't very long anyhow ...

Comment: I know historically there was such behavior.

Comment: I believe the Lev Tahor in Canada do.

Comment: It is interesting to note that the Rambam holds (Hilchot Issurei Biah 21:17) that single girls must cover their hair just like married women.

Comment: But do any communities in Israel or America follow this ruling? @AEML

Comment: Apparently not, I'm just bringing this up because I think this is a source for Sephardic single women covering their hair during prayer, etc. as Avraham quoted from R' Ovadia Yosef @DoubleAA

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29417/2091

Comment: @DoubleAA yes, the girls in the Israeli burqa cults (there are two, one is Bruria Keren's and the other is for FFBs but I forget who leads it). Whether they are considered "legitimate" Orthodox Jewish communities is another question

Comment: Why do you specify Satmar? Why do you think they would be different?

Answer (score 6):

Sefardic women have a custom of covering when praying.
See Yabia Omer,Yalkut Yosef or Halacha Berurah 2:19, where he says to be strict and cover when mentioning God's name, learning the Bible, saying blessings, bircat hamazon, or praying.
In any case he brings that widespread practice is that single girls don't cover her hair.

Comment: A citation would be nice.

Comment: Halacha Berurah 2:19.

Comment: Citation here: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/29441/2091

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Answer (score 2):

It is not true that there aren't communities where this is done, rather most people are just ignorant to the fact that there are. These communities are not only found in Israel but other places as well. What happens is that often times, they keep to themselves, and people assume that the young single girls are married when they see them in public so they just don't know. The married women wear a double head covering just like men in many fervently orthodox communities do. This is the radid, the traditional Jewish (think Biblical) veil. This is still done in Yemen and in recently founded Yemenite diasporic communities including in NYC and in its suburbs. Since people tend to get tunnel vision, they don't notice that these girls don't have wedding rings on.

Comment: Where in NYC did you see teimoni girls wear a double head covering? I pray at 2 teimoni shuls and been at a third. I have yet to hear from anyone in the shul that their daughters cover their hair like this. I personally ask because I want a shedding that does cover their hair this way.

Comment: @MoriDoweedhYaAgob I didn't SEE the girls. I've been told about these communities from people who I know personally who live in he areas where they are. At least one exists in Borough Park, and another in Monsey, NY. To my knowledge, BOTH communities are essentially invisible, or at least their single daughters are. I saw the rabbanit at Tifereth Israel in Manhattan with a radid once, probably the only time I ever saw her. I know little to nothing about both communities, and to my knowledge at least in Monsey, they're EXTREMELY secretive and reclusive. Can't say I blame them. Here's the kicker

Comment: @privategirl I live in boro park and I never seem anyone wearing the niqaab besides Muslim women, unless they wear jewish and I just didn't know. However their kids were dark like Pakistanis which are common on boro park so I don't know.maybe I should look closer

Comment: Lev Tahor's girls wear a single garment from top to toe called a _redid_.

Comment: @nbz that is according to the RaMbaM who says girls should cover from about age 3 in a rodheedh.

Comment: @MoriDoweedhYa3gob I have seen Rambam's requirement of _redid_ for married women (Ishus 24:12), and also his requirement of girls to cover their hair (Issurei Biah 21:17), but where does he require _redid_ for girls?

Comment: @nbz sorry rodheedh is for married women ontop of the meetpa7ath. girls wear only meetpa7ath.

Comment: 3 years past and i still didnt meet anyone girl that isnt married that is covering her hair. i have been to the teimoni community in monsey once and i havent seen any unmarried girl wearing a covering. they all look like the ashkanazi girls around them. wearing a uniform and stockings. they came fairly recently and only the mothers still wear the rodheedh.

Comment: in both batei kannasath here in boro park as well as in the two in flatbush, there are 3 people that wear a jalabiyya. 1 of them me another being a older man that came from yaman(week days he wears hassidic garbs, and a young guy that has a teimoni father and ashkanaziyya mother. the last 2 guys hardly come for shabbothoth as they live far form the kanisa. usually just come on yome tov. no one here is traditional in dress. they are more modern guys from israel and americanized

Answer (score 1):

Recently in Israel there are stories of a cult that does not exist in the United States. The information I've found about the cut can be read here:

[Face-Covering Families in Beit Shemesh: A Destructive Cult?](http://www.amotherinisrael.com/facecovering-families-beit-shemesh-destructive-cult/)

[Jewish Face-Covering Women Request New School](http://www.amotherinisrael.com/jewish-facecovering-women-request-school/)

Comment: This answer has gotten a couple of up-votes, despite it being factually wrong. See user2631's answer and its comments.

Answer (score 1):

The Magein Avraham in siman 75 s.k. 3 has an interesting aproach to the subject. In order to mantain that the Shulchan Aruch does not contradict itself and to maintain the Rambam's opinion in light of a seemingly contradictory Gemara, he asserts that the pruas rosh that is assur for a single girl does not simply mean uncovered, but rather means let lose.

And there are communities that are very strict that single girls not walk with lose hair. Most hassidic communities keep girls hair in ponies. In some Israeli communities, old time Meah Shaarim comes to mind, the girls keep their hair in braids.

These minhagim are all built off the Magen Avraham and his understanding of Pruas Rosh by single girls. So in that sense, many people are stringent on this, even today. But even the Magen Avraham points out this is only a Rabbinic degree of tznius, not biblical.